# i am trying to create a number pattern in java. There is a slight error in the condition of the second inner for loop. I am not able to rectify it

Tags: java, numbers

the pattern is supposed to look like this:

```
 1234
 2345
 3456
 4567
```

i have divided it into two seperate triangles:(n is the number of lines.in this case 4)

```
 1234
 234 5
 34 56
 4 567
```

i have done this much.Please help.

```
public class pattern

{
    void main(int n)
    {
        for(int i =1;i <= n; i++)
     {
        for(int j = i;j<=n;j++)
        {System.out.print(j);}
        for(int j = n+1;j<=(i*2)-1;j++)
        {System.out.print(j);}

        System.out.println();

    }


   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly modified @Pedro Fraga's answer

```
public class pattern
{
void main(int n)
{
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   {
       for (int a = i; a < i + n; a++) 
            {System.out.print(a);}

     System.out.println();
   }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - with one for loop

```
    int count = 0;
    int size = list.size();
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, size - count) + " " + s.substring(size - count));
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have tried a little harder..

I think this is the answer tho:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int a = i; a < i + n; a++) 
        System.out.print(a + 1);
    System.out.println();
}
```